# How to connect mysql in DO droplet from specific ip?

Tags: mysql, ssh, ip, digital-ocean, droplet

As far as I understand my problem is about ip and network knowledge.

I have set up Mysql on Digital Ocean droplet. I want to connect to it from my local pc. Actually I did it by applying several steps like:

- Setting up firewall and allowing **all Ip's**
- Commenting out *bind 127.0.0.1* in */etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf*

My problem is that I need to allow all ips and I cannot set specific port.

I have checked my local pc's IPv4 ip and put it on

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.2 ip to any port 3306
```

and

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'192.168.1.2' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But it does not work and it says it is not my ip. I just checked my network ip and I see something like **192.168.1.2** but it does not work. What kind of ip should I write to these configs and where can I find this ip ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

192.168.1.2 is your internal address on your local network, you must find out your computer's external address

Comment: Digital Ocean is probably suggesting a wrong IP address. You can access https://whatismyipaddress.com and check you external IP